# Non-Midnight "Day" Transition for Apple Watch Activity Rings?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, watchos, activity.app

I often work out at the gym late at night. I also often stay up past midnight.

But the Apple Watch considers each "day" to begin and end at midnight.

This means that I will be in the middle of a workout, trying to complete my Activity Rings for the day, and the activity will suddenly start counting towards tomorrow's "day".

[image: Going to the gym near midnight]

Is it possible to **change the hour on which the Apple Watch begins counting a new day**? I would like to move it to a time when I am most likely always sleeping, such as 4 AM.

This would also be very valuable for people on non-standard schedules, such as a night shift.

Related:

- [Night shift worker question. Is there a way to change to start my next day at noon instead of midnight?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AppleWatch/comments/8qgfzn/night_shift_worker_question_is_there_a_way_to/)